# Adding a time in a dropdownlist and date in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net form where I have the date in a text box `txtdatetime.text` and time in a drop down list which shows time as "11:43PM" or "12:30AM" etc.

In order to run a query, I would like to add both the values into a date value. Can anyone tell me how its possible?

```
DateTime date = txtdatetime.text;
dateTime time = ddltime.selectedvalue;

datetime combo = date + time ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date  + " " + time);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date  + " " + time, "dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date and time are in a format the `DateTime` parser can understand, use this code to convert the two back into a valid `DateTime`.

```
var combo = DateTime
    .Parse(txtDataTime.Text)
    .Add(DateTime.Parse(ddlTime.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: hey Nathan Thanks ! but as I mentioned above the time in my drop down list is in this format : "11:43PM" or "12:30AM"